# CPU upgrade on motherboard Pegatron Benicia 1.01?

Tags: processor, gaming, pc, upgrade

I've never planned to upgrade my CPU.  However, most of the components in my PC have been upgraded, and the CPU is now the performance bottleneck. It doesn't flinch except for gaming where it is maxed out, while the GPU still have quite a way to go before being maxed out.

The Intel CPU is the [Core 2 Quad Q6600](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/29765/intel-core-2-quad-processor-q6600-8m-cache-2-40-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html) and is now worth 10$ on ebay.  In the same Intel CPU family, there is the [Core 2 Quad Q9650](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/35428/intel-core-2-quad-processor-q9650-12m-cache-3-00-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb.html) at around 20$.

So for around 10$ net, I could switch from *2.4 GHz* to *3 GHz*.   This is quite cheap to upgrade, but I'm clueless as to how much better it would be. Also, there might be some other potential compatible models that I'm unaware of because I don't know what I should look at to know if a CPU is compatible or not with the [Pegatron-made](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01324212) [Benicia 1.01](https://mobilespecs.net/motherboard/Pegatron/Pegatron_Benicia_1-01.html). I'm guessing CPUs released today don't fit anymore.

According to pc-specs, the CPU socket for the Pegatron Benicia 1.01 is [BGA 1023](http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/index.html). Does that means that any CPU with this socket is compatible?

- Is there even suitable upgrade candidate?
- If so, what compatible CPU would be a significant upgrade?
- If there are, what should I look at to know if they are compatible or not?
- I would have used a compatibility sites to find out, but all of those I've tried aren't even aware of the motherboard because it is so old.... Those who did recommended some crazy up to date CPU which instantly made me suspicious of their credibility...

I know there are many questions here, but hopefully these questions will help understand the needs.

Comment: Hello there. What exactly is your PC? Desktop, laptop? You've given no info besides the motherboard. Its quite impossible your socket is BGA1023 for this motherboard. The Q6600 isn't manufactured with that socket.

Comment: It is à hp pavillons élite. It's a desktop.  I'm on my Phone, I'll add others specifications once i-my back home. What other specifications is needed? Bios versions?

Comment: I can already tell you: the Q9650 is compatible with your computer for sure. I'll create an answer.

Comment: I ended up not buying anything and overclocked with TAPE BSEL MOD.
The cores now run at 3 Ghz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Benicia motherboard supports many processors. Per [HP documentation](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c01301711) it should support this [list](http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/pegatron-corporation-1-01-benicia-motherboard-specs/) of CPU:

[image]

The absolute best CPU available on this platform is the **Q9650.** As for speed gains, it gives a difference of about **50% faster** at *best.* 
[Q9650 vs Q6600 comparison](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core2-Quad-Q9650-vs-Intel-Core2-Quad-Q6600/m1706vs1980) Anything else than a Q**** series processor is a downgrade for you.

Now: is it worth it? 50% isn't really a big boost in speed, and if **you will still have the processor as a bottleneck.** To give a comparison, the *cheapest* Ryzen 5 setup will be at least **100-200% faster** depending on the application. 
[Ryzen 5 vs Q6600](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/AMD-Ryzen-5-2500U-vs-Intel-Core2-Quad-Q6600/m378273vs1980)

Of course, changing platform will force you to change your RAM, motherboard, and CPU. As well as maybe your power supply. The price for that is way above the price for a single Q9650. I suggest you get a Q9650 for now anyways and save money for a new build eventually.

P.S. Be careful not to buy a Q**X**9650. These wont work. It's a **Q9650**, without the X.

Comment: Great!, Yes, I'll get a new pc eventually, but for now the timing is wrong. 
Also, thumb up for the warning between QX and Q.

Comment: I've got room on the power supply. Some seller on ebay have some Xeon X5470 modified to be compatible with 775 socket. [This model would give 71% improvement best the Q9650.](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Xeon-X5470-vs-Intel-Core2-Quad-Q6600/m14102vs1980) Vendor offer to verify compatibility, I'll check with them.

Comment: @AXMIM That's the kind of processor that probably will not work. Don't buy modified CPU. You'll have other problems with them most often.

Answer (score 1):

I went the Q9650 route and maxed out the ram and bought an  MSI Geforce GT1030 GPU and less than $200 my 15 year old HP pavilion has received a new lease on life, it handles Valorant and other online games just fine (Not triple A games though). (I upgraded the Power supply to a 450W earlier so it isn't the original one).